# how to send class data in to a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a button to display a form to enter a class name in the input.

After that 1 button will exist (it is hidden after I click a button it will appear ) then after I press a Hidden button it will go to another page, but the problem is I don't know how to make the hidden button ( with data in it ) visible.

Here's my code:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const btnn = document.getElementById("name").value;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const form = document.getElementById("Add");

  if (form.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
    form.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    form.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
});

btnn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const but = document.getElementById("infor");

  if (but.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
    but.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    but.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

})
```

```css
form {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 60%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tablinks {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.btnn {
  background-color: white;
}

.information {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#infor {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="information.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" id="btn">Add here</button>
  </div>
  <form id="Add" class="information">
    <p>Class:</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter your class here" id="name">
    <button>Add</button>
    <button id="infor"></button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please use Google translate and type your question on there in your mother language and then translate it to English? It's very difficult to understand your question and once you can make it more clear, I will help you to solve it:) Also you have to remove the ".value" from "document.getElementById("name").value" if you need to add an event to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute to button tags inside the form, as they behave like a submit button.

```
<button type="button"></button>
```